# How to I make my rim brakes stop making loud ugly noises ?

Tags: rims

I just bought a new bike today, and I took it out for a test ride and the brakes just make a super ugly and loud noise when I use them, my brother says I just have to break them in , but some of my friends say I have to get new brakes ? Anyone help

Comment: Three things:  1) To some extent you just need to break in the brakes.  2) The brake pads need to be "toed in".  A new bike should have the pads toed in, but "should have" and "has" are different things.  If you bought the bike from a respectable shop, take it back in a week or two (after a little "break in" for other components, in addition to the brakes) and get what should be a free adjustment service.  3) If the pads still squeak you can exchange the pads for ones of a different material.  Some pads squeak more than others.

Comment: @Criggie - Read the title.

Comment: Check the alignment and hardness of the pads. Old pads get hard and brake poorly, when they've been sitting around for a few years.

Answer (score 1):

After greasing my chain, some grease got on the rim of my tire.  It made a **terrible** noise while braking.

Sand grains that has gotten stuck in the brake pad can also cause screeching noises.

I recommend try to make sure there is no debris around the brakes.  Also make sure the rim is very clean.  Scrub it down to remove all oils, greases and debris.